# Chaining video adapters (DVI-to-VGA-to-Composite)

Tags: cable, adapter

I'm working on hooking up output from an old laptop to our TV.  I'd like to use Composite input (L/R/Video), but I'm having a hard time finding a DVI-to-Composite video cable.

Can I use a DVI-to-VGA adapter before running it through a VGA-to-Composite like the one in the image?  Most of them say something like "Your VGA card must support TV out directly through VGA port", and I don't know if a DVI-to-VGA adapter will do so.

[image: VGA-to-Composite cable]

<sub>(In this scenario, sound will be handled by a headphone-to-RCA splitter, which will be joined with the video to make composite)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect most if not all TVs will expect a standard video signal if you are sending it composite. It is unlikely that a computer will generate this. Simply using a number of connector adaptors will not do the job. You need something that has processing circuitry.

A standard video signal has  a frame rate of 25 or 29.97 frames per second [or 50 or 59.94 if progressive HD]. The other thing is the image size - SD versions depend on where you are in the world. HD may be 720 lines or 1080.

The composite signal combines the red, green and blue signals onto one wire using either PAL or NTSC coding. Unless your computer explicitly can generate that, or you have a somesort of convertor, the signal out of your computer can not be connected to the composite connector by simple passive cables.

Looking at my laptops video card options - it will not support SD resolutions and it will not support 25 or 29.97 frames per second.

You can by boxes that will process the video from one format to another - e.g.DVI in SDI out. Not sure abut DVI to PAL/NTSC.

So, unless your cables have active electronic porcessing to convert the signal from one format to another then you can not go from computer to TV. Sorry to bring bad news.

Comment: Hmm.  Good answer, and it makes sense.  That would explain the "TV out" requirement.  Annoying, though.